# why SameSite Lax sends the cookie to POST XHR request to cross origin when credentials: 'include' is set?

Tags: cookies, cors, samesite

As I read on the internet, SameSite=Lax can't send the cookie with POST XHR request to cross-origin. I tried to replicate this behavior

I hosted frontend on :8080

```html
    <button onclick="callPostApiCrossSite()">Call POST CrossSite</button>
    <script>
        const crossSiteUrl = "http://localhost:8081"
        const optionsForPost = {
            method: 'POST',
            credentials: 'include',
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            },
        }
        var x = fetch(`${crossSiteUrl}/crossSite`, optionsForPost)
        console.log(x);
    </script>
```

```js
http.createServer(function (request, response) {
    try {
        // log the request on console
        console.log(request.url);
        // Dispatch
        dispatcher1.dispatch(request, response);
    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
    }
}).listen(8081);

    
dispatcher1.on("options", "/crossSite", function(request, response) {
    console.log("option is called");
    response.writeHeader(200, { 
        "Access-Control-Allow-Credentials": "true",
        "Access-Control-Allow-Methods": "GET,POST" ,
        "Access-Control-Allow-Headers": "content-type",
        "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "http://localhost:8080",
    });
    response.end();
})
dispatcher1.onPost("/crossSite", function (request, response) {
    console.log("8081 Post Cookie: ", request.headers["cookie"])
    response.writeHeader(200, { "Content-Type": "application/json",
    "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "http://localhost:8080",
    "Access-Control-Allow-Credentials": "true", });    
    response.write('{"Statue": "OK"}')
    response.end();
});
```

I had a cookie in the browser with sameSite=Lax.
I from the front end (hosted on :8080) sent a post request (by clicking button) to :8081 with the POST HTTP method. Then, instead of the browser throwing a CORS error, it enabled the response for the front end.
I was able to log the cookie and the browser didn't throw any CORS error.

Is this the expected behavior, Can anybody explain?

Comment: Your test-case is not representative of the public web: browsers have special-rules for `localhost` vs. Internet hosts, and the fact you're using `http:` (instead of `https:`) may play a part too. Additionally, the way Cookies are partitioned by domain (instead of Origin) probably matters too.

Comment: A request is cross-site only if origin and target have different eTLD+1 (roughly, `.frontend.com` vs. `.backend.com`), the port does not matter at all. Therefore, a request from `localhost:8080` to `localhost:8081` is same-site (but cross-origin).

Comment: Origin != site. See https://jub0bs.com/posts/2021-01-29-great-samesite-confusion/

Comment: @HeikoTheißen In the modern definition of site, the scheme is also considered. What you're describing is now known as _schemelessly samesite_.